# Copy/paste values on two sheets

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I'm trying to copy values from one sheet to another sheet if a value exists. The code runs great on around 500 rows but very slowly on 5000 rows.

Is there any way I can speed it up?

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub ExampleCycleCount()
    ' updating off
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Calculation = xlManual
    End With

    Dim FileName As String
    Dim FilePath As String
        FileName = Format(Now, "YYYY MM DD HHMM") & " " & _
                   Sheets("WarehouseInventory").Range("A1").Text
        FilePath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Cycle Count"

    Debug.Print FileName

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "\" & FileName

    ' Check if active sheet name is scan report
    If Not ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Scan Report" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "Scan Report"
    End If

    Dim SCAN_REPORT As Worksheet
    Dim INVENTORY_REPORT As Worksheet
    Set SCAN_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scan Report")
    Set INVENTORY_REPORT = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("WarehouseInventory")

    ' Add top row for heading -
    With SCAN_REPORT
        If Not [A1].Value = "LPN" Then
            Rows("1:1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            [A1].Value = "LPN"
            [B1].Value = "PART NUMBER"
            [C1].Value = "SERIAL NUMBER"
            [D1].Value = "SYSTEM BIN"
            [E1].Value = "SCANNED BIN"
            [F1].Value = "COMMENT'S"
        End If

        ' set filter mode
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False Then
            [A1].AutoFilter
        End If

        With ActiveWindow
            .SplitColumn = 0
            .SplitRow = 1
            .FreezePanes = True
        End With

    End With

    Dim i%, x% ' as long
        i = 2 ' Start on row 2 - SCAN_REPORT
        x = 3 ' Start on row 3 - INVENTORY_REPORT

    Dim BIN_NUM As String
    Dim LPN_NUM As String

    With SCAN_REPORT
        Do Until IsEmpty(.Columns(1).Cells(i))
            DoEvents

            If Len(.Columns(1).Cells(i).Value) <= 6 Then
                BIN_NUM = .Columns(1).Cells(i).Value
                Debug.Print BIN_NUM 'Immediate Window
            End If

            If Len(.Columns(1).Cells(i).Value) = 12 Then
                Debug.Print .Columns(1).Cells(i).Address
                LPN_NUM = .Columns(1).Cells(i).Value

                With INVENTORY_REPORT
                    Do Until IsEmpty(.Columns(1).Cells(x))
                        DoEvents

                        If .Columns(1).Cells(x).Value = LPN_NUM Then
                            ' Copy Paste from inventory to scan sheet
                            SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
                            INVENTORY_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(x).Offset(0, 1).Value

                            SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 2).Value = _
                            INVENTORY_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(x).Offset(0, 2).Value

                            SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 3).Value = _
                            INVENTORY_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(x).Offset(0, 3).Value

                            SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 4).Value = BIN_NUM

                            ' Check if bin row match
                            If Not SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 3) _
                                                         .Value = BIN_NUM Then

                                SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 5) _
                                           .Value = "SYSTEM/SCAN BIN DON'T MATCH"
                            End If

                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        x = x + 1
                    Loop

                    x = 2
                End With 'INVENTORY_REPORT

                If SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 4).Value = "" Then
                    SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 4).Value = BIN_NUM
                    SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 5).Value = "LPN NOT FOUND"
                End If
            Else
                If Len(.Columns(1).Cells(i).Value) >= 7 Then
                    SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 5) _
                                          .Value = "ERROR / SCANNED IN " & BIN_NUM
                End If
            End If

            i = i + 1
        Loop

    End With 'SCAN_REPORT

    With INVENTORY_REPORT
        .Range("H2").Value = "COMMENTS'S"
        .Range("H2").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A2").AutoFilter
    End With

    x = 0 ' INVENTORY_REPORT
    i = 0 ' SCAN_REPORT

    Dim List As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set List = New Scripting.Dictionary

    With SCAN_REPORT
        Dim Rpt_LRow As Long
            Rpt_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Rpt_Data() As Variant
            Rpt_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Rpt_LRow, 1)).Value

        For x = LBound(Rpt_Data) To UBound(Rpt_Data) Step 1
            DoEvents
            Debug.Print Rpt_Data(x, 1)
            On Error Resume Next ' For duplicates
            List.Add Rpt_Data(x, 1), x
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    End With

    With INVENTORY_REPORT
        Dim Inv_LRow As Long
            Inv_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Inv_Data() As Variant
            Inv_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(Inv_LRow, 1)).Value

        For i = LBound(Inv_Data) To UBound(Inv_Data) Step 1
            DoEvents
            If List.Exists(Inv_Data(i, 1)) Then
                .Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 7).Value = "LPN SCANNED"
            Else
                .Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 7).Value = "LPN NOT SCAN"
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' Check for dupes
    With SCAN_REPORT.Range("A:A")
        .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        .FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = 13551615
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .Calculation = xlAutomatic
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `Debug.Print`?

Comment: @Raystafarian Just for testing, it will get removed once the code is ready-

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook, might be easier to recommend performance tweaks understanding the full context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of aspects to this code. I'll just address your loops, but first

First - while this notation works

> ```
> If .Columns(1).Cells(x).Value = LPN_NUM Then
> ```

It's not standard. It's actually very strange.

```
If .Cells(x,1) = LPN_NUM
```

Is more like how it would be expected to be used.

---

#### Loops

I don't like `DO UNTIL` loops. I especially don't like a `DO UNTIL` in my `DO UNTIL`. Also, let's take a look at these

> ```
> With SCAN_REPORT
>     Do Until IsEmpty(.Columns(1).Cells(i))
>         DoEvents
>         With INVENTORY_REPORT
>             Do Until IsEmpty(.Columns(1).Cells(x))
>                 DoEvents
>                 x = x + 1
>             Loop
>             x = 2
>         End With
>         i = i + 1
>     Loop
> End With
> ```

What's happening here? I can't really tell by just looking at it. Let's start with some structure -

```
    Dim scanLastRow As Long
    Dim inventoryLastRow As Long
    scanLastRow = SCAN_REPORT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    inventoryLastRow = INVENTORY_REPORT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Okay, now we can use some `FOR NEXT` loops

```
    For x = 1 To scanLastRow
        With INVENTORY_REPORT
            For i = 1 To inventoryLastRow
            Next
        End With
    Next
```

Right, that feels better.

> ```
> Dim Rpt_LRow As Long
> Rpt_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
> Dim Inv_LRow As Long
> Inv_LRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
> ```

Look, in fact you've already written that code.

---

Okay, let's talk about speed in your loops.

Things like this

> ```
> SCAN_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(i).Offset(0, 1).Value = _
>  INVENTORY_REPORT.Columns(1).Cells(x).Offset(0, 1).Value
> ```

Take a lot of resources. Especially within two `DO UNTIL` loops. Looking at it, it kind of looks like you want something like this

```
Dim invArray As Variant
Dim scanArray As Variant
Dim scanLastRow As Long
Dim inventoryLastRow As Long
scanLastRow = SCAN_REPORT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
inventoryLastRow = INVENTORY_REPORT.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
scanArray = SCAN_REPORT.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(scanLastRow, 4))
inarray = INVENTORY_REPORT.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(inventoryLastRow, 4))
Dim scanIndex As Long
Dim invIndex As Long
For scanIndex = LBound(scanArray) To UBound(scanArray)
    LPN_NUM = scanArray(scanIndex)
    For invIndex = LBound(invArray) To UBound(invArray)
        If invArray(invIndex) = LPN_NUM Then
            'stuff
        Else
            'other stuff
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Now you can loop through the items in the arrays rather than on the sheet. Populate the arrays and then put the array on the sheet in one fell swoop.